# How to instantiate an GameObject of Custom Class in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

I have a script called `GamePiece` and it is attached to prefabs. Now I want to spawn random game pieces from the `GamePiece[] gamePieces` which contains all prefabs.

```
    private IEnumerator SpawningRandomObjects()
    {
        Debug.Log("in SpawningRandomObjects");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(2f, waitSpawnTime));
        Vector3 randomPosition = RandomPosition();

        GamePiece spawned = Instantiate<GamePiece>(RandomGamePiece(gamePieces), randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        Debug.Log("second to last line in SpawningRandomObjects"); //never comes to this line
        //yield return new WaitUntil(() => drinkRef.FreezeSpawn());
    }

    private GamePiece RandomGamePiece(GamePiece[] gamePieces)
    {
        return gamePieces[Random.Range(0, gamePieces.Length)];
    }
```

It seems to run and the game pieces get instantiated when i build and run the game on a mobile device. But in Xcode when I run the game it shows the error shown above periodically (since I call this function in the Update).

I dont quite understand how to instantiate them in the game because `Instantiate()` throws following error:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'GameObject' to type 'GamePiece'.
  at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at SpawnObjects+<SpawningRandomObjects>d__16.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

[image: this is an example game piece prefab]

Here is the `Update()`function where I call the `SpawnRandomObjects()` function. Note that the foreach loop and its containing debug logs are also never printed during run.

```
void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log("start checking ground: " + groundPlacement.GroundSet());
        if (groundPlacement.GroundSet())
        {
            if (FreeSpawnSpotsAvailable())
            {
                Debug.Log("start spawn");
                StartCoroutine(SpawningRandomObjects());

                foreach (GamePiece piece in spawnedPieces)
                {
                    Debug.Log("spawnedPieces:\n" + piece.name + piece.transform.position);
                }
            }

            //Debug.Log(maxSpawns + " maxSpawns\n" + occupiedSpawnSpot + " occupiedSpawnSpots\n" + (maxSpawns - occupiedSpawnSpot) + " free spawn spots");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what your issue is here, I copy and pasted your code and it seems to run absolutley fine. Can you give us more information about the rest of your code and prefabs?

Comment: As an additional test, you can try doing `Instantiate(RandomGamePiece(gamePieces)...` and then try to retrieve the `GamePiece` instance using `GetComponent<GamePiece>` just to validate that your instantiated object is implementing the GamePiece script.  Your code looks good but this might help identify where the problem is.

Comment: Maye for extra information: the second debug line in SpawningRandomObjects() does not get printed. So I know the `Instantiate` line throws something.

Comment: @Jay It seems to run and the game pieces get instantiated when i build and run the game on a mobile device. But in Xcode when I run the game it shows the error shown above periodically (since I call this function in the Update)

Comment: Wait, the script is attached to a child object? How are you setting the reference in `gamePeices[]` then? Does the parent object also have this compoent attached

Comment: So the error only exits in certain builds? Does it work in the editor? (Please edit this info into your question rather than replying as a comment, comments get deleted sometimes)

Comment: @Jay you are right thanks! I fixed the problem by attaching the script to the parent instead of the child. I didnt see that the object that has the SpawnScript (codes I showed above) has missing pieces in the gamePieces[] since the type didn't match

Answer (score 0):

The `GamePiece` script was on the child object of the prefab which was not enough (I didnt know that).

I fixed this error by attaching the `GamePiece` script to the parent object of the prefab instead. This way the `gamePieces[]` was detecting my prefabs.

Important: I had to change some code for example those containing `GetComponent` into `GetComponentInChildren`